# Does frequency modulation by direct method cause any phase modulation?

Tags: frequency-modulation

Phase modulation causes instantaneous frequency to vary according to modulating signal.
In the same way does Frequency modulation by direct method causes any phase variation in proportion to modulating signal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Frequency is the derivative of phase over time. So you can't modulate one without changing the other.

Comment: Thank you marcus

Comment: It seems from equations : 
FM by m(t) results in PM by 2*pi*m(t).t
where as PM by m(t) results in FM by (1/(2*pi)) * d/dt(m(t))

Comment: yes. again, frequency is the derivative of phase. No matter how you modulate a signal, you cannot effect one without affecting the other.